# Actionscript 3.0 object position to hide other objects

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to make a drag and drop game where one of the conditions is when one object is placed into a certain position, the next step is supposed to appear.

I'm very very new to coding and pretty much flying blind for the most part. I created this code but I'm not sure if I am writing it right to get my game to function correctly

```
  gamefacetemplate.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag_2);

function fl_ClickToDrag_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gamefacetemplate.startDrag();
}

gamefacetemplate.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, fl_ObjectPosition);

function fl_ObjectPosition(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gamefacetemplate.x = 706.90;
    gamefacetemplate.y = 311.90;
}

gamefacetemplate.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MoveToHide_6);

function fl_MoveToHide_6(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    instrustep2.visible = false;
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ReleaseToDrop);

function fl_ReleaseToDrop(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gamefacetemplate.stopDrag();
}

{
gamefacetemplate.visible = false;
}

{
    gotoAndStop(5);
}
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: first, the last two lines between the curly brackets are incorrect. It looks like you may have wanted to define a function there? Second, I don't see anything that looks like a conditional.

Answer (score 0):

i give you 2 exemples, i didn't understand very well the intrustep object so i just removed it ;) 
The following codes just used to drag the gamefacetemplate object to a position (i added margins to the position so it's more flexible) if you drag to the right position you go to frame 5 else the object return to the initial position. So there are two solutions:

if you want the drag to position activate next step:

```
gamefacetemplate.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag_2);

// maybe you want to keep te original position of the dragin object
var originalPos:Point;

function fl_ClickToDrag_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    // keep original position
    originalPos = new Point( gamefacetemplate.x, gamefacetemplate.y );

    // start dragging
    gamefacetemplate.startDrag();

    // listen mouse mouve event
    gamefacetemplate.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, fl_ObjectPosition);

    // listen mouse up event
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop);
}

function fl_ObjectPosition(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   // test if the object is in a range of acceptable position
   if( gamefacetemplate.x > 650 && gamefacetemplate < 750 && gamefacetemplate.y > 250 && gamefacetemplate.y < 350 )
   {
       // place item at the right position
       gamefacetemplate.x = 706;
       gamefacetemplate.y = 311;

       // stop dragging
       gamefacetemplate.stopDrag();

       // and so remove the listeners
       stage.aremoveEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop);
       gamefacetemplate.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag_2);
       gamefacetemplate.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, fl_ObjectPosition);

       // and maybe activate next step
       gotoAndStop(5);
   }
}

function fl_ReleaseToDrop(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // stop dragging
    gamefacetemplate.stopDrag();

    // replace item at original position
    gamefacetemplate.x = originalPos.x;
    gamefacetemplate.y = originalPos.y;

    // and so remove the listeners
    stage.aremoveEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop);
    gamefacetemplate.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, fl_ObjectPosition);
}
```

or if you want the drop to position activate next step:

```
gamefacetemplate.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag_2);

// maybe you want to keep te original position of the dragin object
var originalPos:Point;

function fl_ClickToDrag_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    // keep original position
    originalPos = new Point( gamefacetemplate.x, gamefacetemplate.y );

    // start dragging
    gamefacetemplate.startDrag();

    // listen for mouse up event
    stage.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ObjectPosition );
}

function fl_ObjectPosition(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    // maybe here you want to stop dragging
    gamefacetemplate.stopDrag();

    // test if the object is in a range of acceptable position
    if( gamefacetemplate.x > 650 && gamefacetemplate < 750 && gamefacetemplate.y > 250 && gamefacetemplate.y < 350 )
    {
       // place item at the right position
       gamefacetemplate.x = 706;
       gamefacetemplate.y = 311;

       // and so remove the listeners
       stage.aremoveEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop);
       gamefacetemplate.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag_2);

       // and maybe activate next step
       gotoAndStop(5);
    }
    else
    {
       // replace item at original position
        gamefacetemplate.x = originalPos.x;
        gamefacetemplate.y = originalPos.y;
    }
}
```